# How to extend a div's width beyond its wrapper?

Tags: html, css

I have a big div wrapper called `<div class="pageWrapper">` for which its size is set to be `1000px`.

Inside it I have a `header` that I want to be `100%` of the screen and `fixed`.

How can I do it ?

I know that I could take off the header `div` outside the `pagewrapper` but I'm customizing a volusion template so to take it off would delete all the CSS that was originally set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/gRW7Q/1/)**</kbd> ?

HTML

```
<div class="pageWrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.pageWrapper {
    width:500px;
    background:green;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.header {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:50px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: use 1000px instead of 500px, I used just to show it in fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see if it works.

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bP5Vd/) as created by  `François Wahl`

```
 width:100%;
 position:fixed;
```

And it is always good if you post the code you have tried first.

Comment: hey thx you for your answer. The thing is that width:100% would give me 1000px wide and not 100%of the screen

Comment: @Ben2pop: Have you tried the suggested solution or you assuming the result? See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bP5Vd/) as a working example of the code from this answer. For the example to be easier to see the wrapper is set to `150px` width instead of `1000px` and the header is set to `position:fixed;` and `width:100%;`. I applied border colors so you can see how it works.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Nice one. I was about to create a fiddle for him :)